# Best practice for temp directory used by MediaWiki?

Tags: apache, mediawiki, best-practices

This question appears to be related to [File system permission for MediaWiki uploads?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/93758/40589) Tightening permissions has lead to *"Error creating thumbnail"* messages:

[image]

MediaWiki has a page on the temp directory at [Manual:$wgTmpDirectory](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgTmpDirectory), but the manual does not discuss it in a security context.

Here's our current setting:

```
$ sudo grep Tmp /var/www/html/w/LocalSettings.php
$wgTmpDirectory     = "{$wgUploadDirectory}/tmp";
```

Our `/etc/php.ini` also has a setting for `upload_tmp_dir`, but its not clear to me why MediaWiki is not using it. I'm guessing it has something to do with security, but again, the MediaWiki manual does not discuss it.

What is the best practice for setting the temp directory for MediaWiki?

Answer (score 1):

Best is not to touch these things and leave them as default. That means according to includes/DefaultSettings.php

```
$wgTmpDirectory = false;
```